# Azure App Service: Converting docx to pdf

Tags: pdf, azure-web-app-service

does someone know if converting docx to pdf is supported with Azure App Service (Standard tier).

I am aware of the GDI+ issue but I didn't find any information what parts aren't supported or if it has changed since those restrictions have been documented.

The reason I am asking is that I have tested a third party component (Aspose.Words for .NET) and it could convert a test docx file to pdf successfully.

And therefore I am wondering if there is a limited set of supported functionality (as the docx file only contains a logo, text and tables) or if I am running in an unsupported gray area.

Thank you!

Best regards,
Johann

Answer (score 1):

I install [Aspose.Words for .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Words/) and do a test to convert docx to pdf on my side, and host web app on my Azure app service (Standard App Service plan/pricing tier), which works fine.

*Code snippet:*

```
HttpPostedFile postedFile = SrcFileUpload.PostedFile;
string dstExtension = "pdf";
string dstFileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName) + "_Converted." + dstExtension;
SaveFormat dstFormat = FileFormatUtil.ExtensionToSaveFormat(dstExtension);


Document doc = new Document(postedFile.InputStream);
doc.Save(Response, dstFileName, ContentDisposition.Inline, SaveOptions.CreateSaveOptions(dstFormat));
Response.End();
```

*Result:*

[image]

You could also refer to “[How to Convert Documents in Windows Azure](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/How+to++Convert+Documents+in+Windows+Azure)" that shows the complete code for converting documents.

Comment: Thanks for your own tests as well. I have tested it too and had the same result. But there are plenty of messages on the web telling that it wouldn't work and Cloud Services should be used instead. 

So, I am just wondering if something has changed that it would be supported now or that we only use a limited set of features in our tests that are supported when converting documenents but when using "advanced" features we would get into trouble because of the GDI+ restrictions. 

But so far I couldn't find any official documenation.

Comment: ``we only use a limited set of features in our tests that are supported when converting documenents but when using "advanced" features we would get into trouble`` I agree with you, perhaps we just use basic features in test sample, so it works fine with Azure app service. In many official samples, we could find application is implemented as a Cloud services WebRole, if possible, I recommend that you could choose Cloud services.